# Jquery Accordion not working in IE7, Syntax Issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion, internet-explorer-7

I built a site that uses using jquery accordion, with some simple functions that control accordion from external navigation links. Ive tested it in all browsers with no problem, but in IE7 the accordion loads completely open and I have no idea why. Any help would be much appreciated.

using jQuery v1.4.4

below is my code.

```
<script>
jQuery().ready(function(){
    $('#slide-menu').accordion({
        autoHeight: false,
        navigation: true,
        active: false,
        collapsible: true ,
        header: ".slide-menuItem",
    });

    $(".slide-menuItem").click(function(event){
          window.location.hash=this.hash;
     });    
});
 </script>

External nav functions that are called from onclick

<script>
function Clicked1(){  
$("#slide-menu").accordion('activate' , 0)
 } 

 function Clicked2(){  
$("#slide-menu").accordion('activate' , 1)
 }  
</script>
```

On page function to force accordion open

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#slide-menu").accordion('activate' , 1)

    });
</script>
```

HTML markup

```
<a  class="slide-menuItem" href="#people"  name="3">people</a>
<div id="content-area">
CONTENT HERE
</div>

<a  class="slide-menuItem" href="#work"  name="4">work</a>
<div id="content-area">
CONTENT HERE
</div>
```

Ive spent two days tying to solve this please help,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `,`:

```
  $('#slide-menu').accordion({
        autoHeight: false,
        navigation: true,
        active: false,
        collapsible: true ,
        header: ".slide-menuItem", <------- RIGHT HERE
    });
```

Kill it and that should resolve the issue